# Array size of enum length gives compilation error

Tags: c, constants, variable-length-array

Have a look at the code below,

This code compiles fine:

```
enum ids {
    X,
    Y,
    NUM_IDS,
}

void some_func(void)
{
    static char* const names[NUM_IDS] = { "name X" , "name Y"};
}
```

However this code doesn't compile: 
*error: storage size of 'names' isn't constant*

```
enum ids {
    X,
    Y,
    NUM_IDS,
}

void some_func(void)
{
    int nr_names = NUM_IDS;
    static char* const names[nr_names] = { "name X" , "name Y"};
}
```

I think I misunderstood the meaning of a constant expression. Is it the case that in second way it is becoming a VLA which is not present in C90? Somebody please clarify.

Comment: You cannot have static or global VLAs

Comment: @Jabberwocky Why is the second case a VLA, but first one isn't?

Comment: Because `NUM_IDS` is a compile time constant. `nr_names` is not

Comment: This is why `constexpr` was introduced in C++11.

Comment: `nr_names` is not known until run-time.  `static char* const names[nr_names]` needs an array size at compile time.  What value did you want `nr_names` to have at compile time?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at [this](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~reeves.92/CSE2421au12/SlidesDay20.pdf), maybe can help you understand better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static char* const names[nr_names]` is a VLA because `nr_names` isn't a constant expression, but a (non-const) `int`. Sure, in this short example it's always equal to `NUM_IDS`, but you still can't do that.

---

On an unrelated side note, it is recommended that the `char` is defined as `const`, as modifying it won't work because it's part of the program's binary (in C++ it wouldn't let you have it non-const):

```
static const char* const names[NUM_IDS] = { "name X" , "name Y" };
```

Comment: Well, if you don't want to change the pointers, it makes sense to have the `const` at both places. So it's not necessarily wrong, it's just that the other `const` is missing.

Comment: "either way the char needs to be const:" --> No. That is not needed here.

Comment: Oh wow, for some reason I though this was C++. You're right, it's not needed. I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that VLAs are not allowed to have static storage duration

Quoting from ISO 9899 6.7.5.2 Array declarators

> If an identifier is declared to be an object with static storage
>   duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.

So, you are not allowed to declare a static VLA in general.  Because `nr_names` is not constant, you are not allowed to use static in your second code.

The first code is correct, as `NUM_IDS` is constant expression.

Other problem with your second code is that a VLA cannot be initialized.

I quote from ISO 9899 6.7.8 Initialization

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown
>   size or an object type that is not a variable length array type